# AWS Rekognition Validation Error when trying to use RecognizeCelebrities

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I have been trying to experiment with the AWS Rekognition but I have been encountering a really weird bug. I keep getting a validation error but I have no Idea why.

Here is my code:

```js
  const client = new RekognitionClient({
    region: "us-east-2",
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
  });
  const image = await imageToBase64("../tests/photos/testImage.jpg");
  // const image = fs.readFileSync("../tests/photos/testImage.jpg");
  // console.log(image);
  const params = {
    Image: {
      Bytes: image,
    },
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
  const command = new RecognizeCelebritiesCommand(JSON.stringify(params));
  console.log(command);
  try {
    const data = await client.send(command);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
```

Here is the console log of the command variable:

```js
RecognizeCelebritiesCommand {
  middlewareStack: {
    add: [Function: add],
    addRelativeTo: [Function: addRelativeTo],
    clone: [Function: clone],
    use: [Function: use],
    remove: [Function: remove],
    removeByTag: [Function: removeByTag],
    concat: [Function: concat],
    applyToStack: [Function: cloneTo],
    identify: [Function: identify],
    resolve: [Function: resolve]
  },
  input: '{"Image":{"Bytes":"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'... 26614 more characters
}
```

I am getting "validation error detected: Value null at 'image' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null" when I run this code. I have tried passing the image in as a bitmap and base64 string to no avail. The image that I am using is less than 5Mbs and is a jpg file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the JS rekognition example in AWS Github. This shows you how to successfully pass an image to a rekognition operation using the AWS SDK for JavaScript version 3 API.

See:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/rekognition/estimate-age-example/src/estimate-age.js

Comment: It didn't like the base64 string for some reason, thanks for the help